# Where do I get the width of the current cell in tabular?

Tags: tables

How do I get the width of the current cell in tabular? *(This is part of a large project I am working on.)*

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\cellwidth}
\def\s@vewidth{%
  \setlength{\cellwidth}{\linewidth} % Set to \linewidth
  \typeout{L\the\cellwidth L}
  \setlength{\cellwidth}{\dimen0} % Set to \dimen0
  \typeout{D\the\cellwidth D}
}

\begin{document}
\typeout{M\the\linewidth M}

\begin{tabular}{|c|l|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
  Text\s@vewidth&More Text\s@vewidth&Even More Text\s@vewidth
\end{tabular}

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

`\s@vewidth` will be expected to store the width of the current cell in some dimension. This has been set to be both `\linewidth` and `\dimen0` based on the advice from
ChatGPT.

But as evidenced by the following output, neither of the above gives the correct solution. The following values are not consistent.

> ```
> M345.0ptM
> L345.0ptL
> D24.88ptD
> L345.0ptL
> D24.88ptD
> L137.9979ptL
> D24.88ptD
> ```

The M value is from the main document. The L and D values are the `\linewidth` and `\dimen0` values (*supposedly* cell widths) from inside the table, respectively.